# Polymorphic XML serialization/deserialization

Tags: .net, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have:

```
public class B     
{
    public string Some { get; set; }
}

public class D : B
{
    public string More { get; set; }
}

[KnownType(typeof(D))]
public class X
{        
    public B[] Col { get; set; }
}
```

I want to automatically read/write XML exactly like:

```
<X>
 <Col>
  <B Some="val1" />
  <D Some="val2" More="val3" />
 </Col>
</X>
```

Neither `XmlSerializer` not `DataContractSerializer` helped me. This XML structure is mandatory.

So question is: can this be achieved or i have to parse that XML manually?

Thanks,
Andrey

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [XmlArrayItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayitemattribute.aspx) with XmlSerializer:

```
public class X
{        
     [XmlArrayItem(typeof(D)),
      XmlArrayItem(typeof(B))]
     public B[] Col { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this also works! thanks! now i don't know which solution to accept :)

Comment: @Abdrey JaredPar really has enough rep ;-)

Comment: thank you, i've been trying different things today and this worked best!

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're having trouble serializing the collection portion of the object.  When serializing a collection in XML which can contain derived types, you need to inform the serializer about all of the derived types which could appear in the collection with the [XmlInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) attribute

```
[KnownType(typeof(D))] 
public class X 
{ 
  [XmlInclude(Type=typeof(B))]
  [XmlInclude(Type=typeof(D))]        
  public B[] Col { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: awesome, it works! thank you very much! even `KnownType` is not needed. `<Col>` gets ripped off but this is ok.

Comment: KnownType is used by DataContractoSerializer, XmlInclude is for XmlSerializer

Comment: thank you for your solution. I will accept Dmitry because his solution also works and he has much less reputation :) i hope you didn't get upset

Comment: I don't believe that this solution works. The AttributeTargets for the `XmlIncludeAttribute` are Class, Struct, Method and Interface, but not Property. Applying XmlInclude to a property in a class results in a compiler error.