# Polymorphic XML Serialization/DeSerialization to C# objects for varying list of nodes

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have an XML file like this

```
<xml>
    <nodes>
        <text/>
        <img/>
        <text/>
    </nodes>
</xml>
```

I want to map C# objects to this, I know how to use XmlArrayItem but only incase where there is only one item type in array. I was thinking how to do it using a base class for img and text nodes. But can anyone show my code for C# attributes that I can use to auto DeSerialize this xml into C# objects. Using LINQ is not needed.

Here is how I plan to do but its not working:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot ( "textfile" )]
public class TextFile
{

    [XmlArray ( "nodes" )]
    [XmlArrayItem ( "text", typeof(NodeText)), XmlArrayItem ( "img", typeof(NodeImg) )]
    public List<NodeBase Nodes
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


}

[Serializable]
public class NodeBase
{
}

[Serializable]
public class NodeText : NodeBase
{


[XmlText]
public String CDataContent
{
        get;
        set;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class NodeImg : NodeBase
{

    [XmlAttribute ( "width" )]
    public Int32 Width
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlAttribute ( "height" )]
    public Int32 Height
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [XmlAttribute ( "src" )]
    public String SourceImgStr
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you looked into the [XmlInclude](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlincludeattribute.aspx) attribute? you can use it to forward-declare descendants of your base class for serialization.

Comment: I have found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071639/polymorphic-xml-serialization-deserialization but can anyone bring a better option.

Comment: @mtjin An Example would be helpfull.

Comment: I have also added my current code

Comment: more [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/83181d16-a048-44e5-b675-a0e8ef82f5b7/), same issue, some bits of code there too.

Comment: and [here](http://unboxedsolutions.com/sean/archive/2004/07/17/249.aspx) too

Answer (score 1):

afaik you don't need the XmlArrayItem attribute with type declarations, just add this to your base class:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(NodeText))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(NodeImg))]
public class NodeBase
{}
```